# Can you generate XML dynamically in GO?

Tags: xml, go

Can you generate XML dynamically in GO? Instead of using a struct and then doing `.Encode` on it?

So something like you can do in Python by using lxml. As in building one Element after another manually and dynamically as needed.

This way I can add only the fields/elements I need based on custom logic.

Comment: "Can you"? Yes, I am pretty sure it's possible. I don't, however, know of a ready-made library to accomplish this. It shouldn't be that hard to build one. This is, however, verging very close to "please recommend me a library".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add dynamic attributes to a type that contains a map, and define a custom marshalling action on this type. There's an example here: [Marshall map to XML in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928770/marshall-map-to-xml-in-go)